# Can objects inherit string representations?

Tags: java, string, object

I have the following problem with displaying an object as a string:

```
class Gast{

    String voorNaam, achterNaam;
    datum geboorteDatum;

    Gast(String vNaam, String aNaam, datum input){

        voorNaam = vNaam;
        achterNaam = aNaam;
        geboorteDatum = input;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return("Naam: " + voorNaam + " " + achterNaam + " " + geboorteDatum);
    }
}
```

here I implemented a way to represent this object in a string, however when I try to use that in this class:

```
class Kamer{

    boolean vrij;
    Gast gast;

    Kamer(){}

    public String toString(){

         if(vrij == true){

             return "De kamer is vrij!";
         }

         else{

             return gast;
         }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
kamer.java:17: error: incompatible types: Gast cannot be converted to String
        return gast;
```

I gave a string representation of the object Gast in its class?
Does the other class not inherit the representation I gave?

Comment: Because `Gast` is not a string.  You have to call `gast.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the error! and made me feel a bit stupid haha. Should i keep the question?

Comment: "Should i keep the question?" you have no choice since it has up-voted answer...

Comment: as you maybe realized i am pretty new on stack overflow community but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
return gast.toString();
```

Edit: Better yet, as suggested by @Andreas comment, use `String.valueOf(gast)` if there is a possibility gast can be null (or just check for null manually)

Comment: Oh no, please no. Don't use `"" + gast`. If `gast` can be null, use `String.valueOf(gast)`, not that bad construct, which compiles to `new StringBuilder().append(gast).toString()`. *<shivers>*

Comment: Followup: `"" + gast` results in: allocate StringBuilder, allocate `char[16]`, allocate `char[?]` for actual length, copy text, allocate `String`, allocate `char[?]`, copy text. 4-5 allocations and 2 copies of the text *for each execution*. All that overhead at runtime, just to save a few keystrokes. *Sorry, pet peeve of mine.*

Comment: @Andreas ok ok, i'll get rid of it :)